# Powershell Editor with debugging and intellisense feature

Tags: c#, .net, windows, powershell

I am new in `Powershell` and trying to write a `Powershell` script which will automate the web application deployment to a windows server. But I don't find any good IDE for this. Right now I am using Notepad++ but that has no **debugging** feature. Is there any IDE or editor for `Powershell` with debugging feature?

Comment: Try the Built-in PowerShell ISE (My Favorite), for More advanced Features, Check SAPIEN PowerShell Studio and Visual Studio PowerShell Kit, However off-topic for SO IMO, not a code related question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think a small googling will give you a lot of answer. There are a lot of options for this.

1. My personal favorite is **Windows PowerShell ISE**. It's builtin and have all of the features you want to develop your script. Checkout this for further reasons.
   https://4sysops.com/archives/10-reasons-for-using-powershell-ise-instead-of-the-powershell-console/
2. You can also try visual studio extension for PowerShell. Check out here :
   https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c9eb3ba8-0c59-4944-9a62-6eee37294597
3. You can also try [PowerShell Plus IDE](https://www.idera.com/productssolutions/freetools/powershellplus). It has feature to **debug** your powershell script and also builtin **intellisense** feature. There is also pre-loaded scripts from `QuickClick Library` which you can use in your script for faster development. Another thing to mention, its free.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try the builtin one.

Comment: @coderhunk you welcome. But please try to googling first as that will give you a lot of answer.. Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have Powershell 3.0 or later, I would recommend the built-in Powershell ISE.

It supports intellisense and debugging. When it stops at a breakpoint you can use the console to explore and modify the variables, call methods etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try it for sure

Answer (score 0):

You can try Powershell Tools for Visual Studio (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c9eb3ba8-0c59-4944-9a62-6eee37294597) or PowerShell ISE (installed with Windows)